# Call Java from Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, java, html

I would like to call my Java methods in an HTML file but I don't how.

Here is the Java Class:

```java
package GET;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiValuedMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.multimap.ArrayListValuedHashMap;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ProductController {

    public MultiValuedMap<String, MultiValuedMap<String, String>> fahrradlenker= new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();
    public MultiValuedMap<String, String> flatbarlenker= new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();
    public MultiValuedMap<String, String> rennradlenker= new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();
    public MultiValuedMap<String, String> bullhornlenker= new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("Duplicates")
    public void lenkertyp() throws  IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


        URL urlForGetRequest = new URL("https://www.maripavi.at/produkt/lenkertyp");
        String readLine = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlForGetRequest.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((readLine = in .readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(readLine);
            } in .close();

            String lenker =response.toString();
            List<String> list = mapper.readValue(lenker, new TypeReference<List<String >>() {});

            for (int i=0; i<list.size();i++){
                String s = list.get(i);
                if (s.contains("Flatbarlenker")){
                    fahrradlenker.put("Flatbarlenker", flatbarlenker);
                }else if (s.contains("Bullhornlenker")){
                    fahrradlenker.put("Bullhornlenker", bullhornlenker);
                }else{
                    fahrradlenker.put("Rennradlenker", rennradlenker);
                }
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("GET NOT WORKED");
        }
    }
```

Here is the HTML file, where I would like to call the Java methods from above:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>Configure your handlebar <a href="../js/call.js" >here</a></p>
    <More-sharebar><a href="../js/call.js" onclick="javascript:f()">More options</a></More-sharebar>
</body>
</html>
```

And I created a JavaScript file to call the Java methods, but this didn't work either:

```js
function f() {
    var lenkertyps = new Packages.GET.ProductController.lenkertyp();
}
```

And here is the structure of my project:

[image]

Comment: Make an ajax call from UI, write handler in Java, and respond with the value you needed in UI, for details visit: https://javapapers.com/ajax/getting-started-with-ajax-using-java/

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you may use classes and functions declared in Java directly from within JavaScript.

Given this, you have 3 main options:

1. Re-write Java classes and functions with JavaScript. It might be possible, unless you need any DB/FS manipulations or storing secret information (like API secrets).
2. Split your Java functionality into reusable one-time operations (for example: write a string into a table of DB), expose those functions as API, use it from the Frontend with JS. This option is extremely hard to implement correctly from scratch, so if you need it, you most likely want to use some framework.
3. Depending on your purposes, you might also want to use [WebAssembly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly).